# Sage endpoint integration

Tags: integration, payload, sage-300

I kept getting this error:
"error": "code":"InvalidPayload","message":"lang": "en-US", "value": "The payload is invalid for this resource.The property 'InvoiceDetails' does not exist on type 'Sage.CA.SBS.ERP.Sage300.AR'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type